# How to populate Mailchimp Lists in drop down on selecting Mailchimp option

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

I want to show Mailchimp Lists when I click Mailchimp option from drop down I have already make API call to get lists from mailchimp now I want to populate this lists on drop down when I click Mailchimp from drop down.

My Html View:

```
<div class="new-intergrtain-sec clearfix">
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <label class="controllabel" for="select">Mailing List Integration</label>
        <select class="slct-currncy required" id="select">
            <option value="">--- Select Integration ---</option>
            <option value="1">MailChimp</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <label class="control-label" for="select2">Select Email Lists</label>
        <select class="slct-currncy required" id="select2">
            <option value="4"></option>
            <option value="5">MailChimp</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Controller where I am getting listing from mailchimp

```
public function getLists(Request $request)
{
    $user_id = $request->user()->id;
    $apikey = DB::table('user_mlc_mailchimp')->where('user_id','=', $user_id)->value('api_key');
    if($apikey){
        $mc = new MailChimp($apikey);
        $mailchimp_ping = $mc->get('lists',['fields' => 'lists.id,lists.name', 'count' => 50]);
        $mailchimp_ping = ['status' => 1, 'message' => 'Lists Found!', 'dataArray' => $mailchimp_ping];
        return Response::json($mailchimp_ping, 200);

    }

    else {
        $errorResponse = [
            'message' => 'Lists not found!',
            'error' => '401'
        ];
        return Response::json( $errorResponse);
    }
}
```

My Route is :

```
Route::get('lists', 'ApiController@getLists');
```

From these I am getting all the lists available on mailchimp with the required get route which I mentioned.
now I want to populate this on my drop down in my HTML view which I have shared with you and my HTML link is:

```
http://localhost:8000/New-Sale-Page
```

and its route :

```
$router->get('/New-Sale-Page', function () use ($router) {
    return view('add-new-sale-page'); 
});
```

I have shared all the possible links from which u can help me I just want to show the mailchimp listing from drop down when I click mailchimp option,

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: call AJAX `onChange` event, then populate JSON into options for second dropdown.

Comment: are u there @Webinion

Comment: My internet was gone off i am there on chat

Comment: u there @webinion